# Query Firestore for daily average for each hour

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So, I am monitoring a fish tank temperature and pH with some sensors and outputing the data to Firestore. I am using javascript to read it, but now I got the need to see the daily average temperature within said time range.

The documents have a temperature field and a timestamp, firestore receives a new doc each minute, but I dont need the average for the entire day, just hourly. I need a way to get the daily average reading only the documents that have a full hour timestamp and also query it for (today, last week, last month) averages. I have no code yet because I literraly have no idea how to make this query.

Comment: Love the concept in the question but it's going to be hard to answer without fully understanding what your FireStore looks like - we need to see it. You should also attempt some code - start with something simple like adding 10 sample documents to FireStore with test data, read them in and get the average. Then expand on that. We are not a code writing service and won't write the code for you but we are happy to assist with existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Strauss,

Came across this post through a random firestore search.

You can make a [cronjob](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that collects records every hour, then calculates the average and dumps it into a new collection. Then after an hour, also collect records from the past hour again and so on.

So you would have 1 collection with all the minute records, and another with hourly-stats. Just read the hourly stats one.

Also, this would save a lot of reads in the long run. Getting data for 1 hour is 1 read (and onces 60 because of the cronjob). instead of 60 each refresh (for example)